# How do I control what parts of my "Developer Story" get exported to PDF?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

The "traditional" CV functionality had a very useful feature where you could actually fine-tune which items you wanted to include when exporting to PDF (and I think it also let you control the order in which certain sections would be exported?).  This was incredibly important for keeping the exported document down to a reasonable length, and for just highlighting the superlatives and/or those items that are most relevant to the specific position being applied for.

With the "Developer Story" version, it looks like every single item that's included in the timeline gets dumped into the exported PDF document.  This results in some unacceptably long and rambling CV's.

Is there any way to control what information gets exported (and preferably, also the order in which it's exported!) when converting the Developer Story to PDF?  I mean, short of deleting things out of the Developer Story itself?

I don't think it's viable to just delete all the items that I don't want to export to my current CV.  If I'm going to have a developer story then it should be a complete and unabridged tale.  However, when I export that to a CV for the purposes of seeking employment I don't want to be boring people to death with my 5-page-long resume.  I need to be able to pick and choose just the best and most relevant items to highlight, and those may actually vary depending upon the position I'm applying to.

If there's currently no way to accomplish this, can it please be added as a feature?

Comment: Pretty similar, yes.  Although the other question is less clear with respect to articulating exactly what features are being requested.  Specifically 1) the ability to exclude selected content from the PDF export, and 2) the ability to influence the order of exported content.

Comment: Why is this marked as a duplicate, when the duplicate question doesn't have an answer?