# Add an option to not include "Recommended reading" when printing Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

It sounds like something you might not want to include when you print a Developer Story out.

Not talking about the web page of the Developer Story.

I'm talking about the page stack overflow generates when you click "Save as PDF"

Answer (score 34):

I believe this is essentially a degenerate version of a feature that's already been requested (*several* times):

- [PDF Export lacks essential customizations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336048/pdf-export-lacks-essential-customizations)
- [How do I control what parts of my "Developer Story" get exported to PDF?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339416/how-do-i-control-what-parts-of-my-developer-story-get-exported-to-pdf)
- [Choose sections to hide when exporting developer story to PDF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321412/choose-sections-to-hide-when-exporting-developer-story-to-pdf?rq=1)

That said, yes, they absolutely need to restore the ability to choose what does/doesn't get included in the PDF export.  The Developer Story is basically unusable to me for its intended purpose (providing a professional, high-quality resume that I can use to seek employment) because this essential feature was carelessly removed.

Comment: how does it work in `stackoverflow meta`? do I select this as the right answer? I'm not sure what's an answer on this sub-site :-)

Comment: @Thatkookooguy, as you've posted a `[feature-request]`, I would accept an answer only when the feature is implemented or rejected.

Comment: @Thatkookooguy you need to ask that question on Meta Meta Stack Overflow... ;)